# Laravel relationships reload

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I haven't found how I can force a model to re-query it`s children.

### Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Model1 extends Model
{
    public function seasons() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Seasons', 'series_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I call `$instanceModel1->seasons();` throughout my application logic I want an element removed along the way.
Is there a way when calling `$instanceModel1->seasons();` a **second** time to force the Eloquent to do a query rather than returning the models already loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Simply reloading the relation works for me.

```
$instanceModel1->load('seasons');
```

Comment: you can also pass an array to load multiple ones:

$instanceModel1->load(['sessions','filters']);